# angular return promise that already has a catch

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a angular service that provides a login function in order to log in a user:

```
app.service('AuthSharedService', function($rootScope, $http, authService, UserSession) {
    this.login = function(email, password, rememberMe) {
        return $http.post('/login',
                {
                    'email': email,
                    'password': password,
                    'rememberMe': rememberMe
                })
            .then(function(response){
                console.log("success 1");
                authService.loginConfirmed(response.data);
            }).catch(function(response){
                console.log("catch 1");
            }).finally(function(response){
                console.log("finally 1");
            });
    };
    return this;
});
```

I also have a controller that is bound to a HTML login formular:

```
app.controller("loginController",
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $window, $http, $routeParams, AuthSharedService){
        var vm = this;
        vm.email;
        vm.password;
        vm.rememberMe;
        vm.login = function (){
            AuthSharedService.login(vm.email, vm.password, vm.rememberMe)
                .then(function(response){
                    console.log("success 2");
                }).catch(function(response){
                    console.log("catch 2");
                });
        }
    }
);
```

So far it is very basic.
But when I delete the database user table and then try to login, I get of course a internal error 500 on the REST server. But the console output of angular then is:

```
catch 1
success 2
```

But why? Can't I return a `$http` in order to use the `.then(function())` and the `.catch(function())` twice?

thanks for any help :)
best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catch` returns a new promise which is successful by default; that allows you to create chains which catch errors and then continue with some default success scenario:

```
returnsPromise()
    .catch(() => 'default value')
    .then(value => alert(value))
```

This will either alert the value from `returnsPromise`, or, if that fails, a default value of `'default value'`.

What you want is to return the original `$http` promise, not the caught promise:

```
let p = $http.post(...);
p.catch(...);
return p;
```

If `post()` fails, the already attached `catch` *and any other error handlers you may attach* will get called if an error occurs. Conversely, only if `p` is successful will the success handlers be called (and `catch` won't).

Answer (score 2):

When you call `.catch`, it returns a promise. If you don't returns anything, it will returns an auto resolved promise.

If you want to keep the promise in an error state after a `.catch`, you can do this:

```
promise
.catch(function(response) {
    handleResponse(response);
    return $q.reject(response);
});
```

You can also do this:

```
var promise = ...;
promise.catch(...);
return promise
```

**But** keep in mind that if the `catch` callback is asynchronous, this code will probably don't behave as you want.